# How can I set a time out for this jQuery code ?

Tags: jquery, animation

This is what I have so far. I want to set a timeout for function `spid()`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#spid").animate({top: '-110px' }, 600, 'easeOutBounce',
    function spid() {
       $(this).animate({top:"-=20px"},1000).animate({top:"+=20px"},1000);
       setTimeout("spid()",2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: for `setInterval` & `setTimeout`, please don't pass the parameter as string. Though it is correct way but time consuming 'cause the the string again needs to be parsed

Comment: this doesn't require an example to explain, I guess You can just think of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("#spid").animate({top: '190px' }, 600,'linear' ,function() {
        (function spid() { 
            console.log('Test'); 
            $(this).animate({top:"+=20px"},1000).animate({top:"+=20px"},1000);
            setTimeout(spid,2000);
        })();   
    });
});
```

There is a problem with `this` in the above code, below code snippet works fine

**Edit** :

```
$(function() {
  $("#spid").animate({top: '110px' }, 600,'linear' ,function() {
    var cache = $(this);
    (function spid() {
      cache.animate({top:"+=20px"},1000).animate({top:"-=20px"},1000);
      setTimeout(spid,2000);
    })();  
  });
});
```

please Test the code **http://jsbin.com/elaxa3**

Comment: this part of the code dosent work $(this).animate({top:"+=20px"},1000).animate({top:"+=20px"},1000);

Comment: nvm its not working  when i put "#spid" instaed of "this" its works otherwise it dosent work

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass in a function.

```
setTimeout( spid,2000 );
```

Or you could also just use `setInterval`.